# Find all functions $f(x)$ where $2f(x)+1=f(2x+1)$ for all real $x$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I have not gotten much except $f(-1)=-1$ from subbing $x=-1$.

If $f$ is linear I get $f(x)=(c+1)x+c$ from subbing $f(x)=ax+b$.

I'm not really sure how to show that $f$ is linear, or narrow it down any further.

Comment: Since you've asked for an explanation, what do you mean, specifically, by the possibility of the problem not being solvable?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is a solution, thus it is solvable

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{a x}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+x$ is the general solution

Comment: Hi @Raffaele, sorry how would you prove this is the only solution? Edit: I think this is the same as I got above, if you take $c=a/2$. I just am not sure how to prove it’s linear

Comment: Sorry may a mod please reopen my question, this was my first post and I didn’t know the forum guidelines. Sorry

Comment: I am not that into functional equations. *Mathematica* gave that result so I assume it is the unique solution

Comment: @Raffaele oh ok thanks

Comment: As far as I can see in this kind of problems they give the solution and... stop. Example https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h346648

Comment: I suspect there will be non-continuous solutions. Knowing $f(x)$ implies knowledge of $f(2x+1)$ and vice versa, but set of points generated by such sequence does not cover whole $\mathbb{R}$, so you could define $f$ for each of these sequences separately (value for any of its representant is sufficient to determine all other), and combine them together to cover $\mathbb{R}$. It might still be possible that linear function is the only continous solution though.

Comment: Maybe you want to narrow down the search to linear functions. In that case, the identity is the only solution (a simple consequence of the definition of linear). As Sil pointed out, there is no hope to prove that every $f$ solving your problem is linear.

Comment: More explicit example of the non-continuous idea: Put $f(x)=x$ for $x=2^k-1$ with integer $k$ and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise, then the functional equation should hold.